# JS - URLSearchParam constructor param type issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to convert an object to queryString using `URLSearchParams()` but it is giving error. How can I fix it?

I CANNOT CHANGE THE `start` AND `end` TO STRING TYPE.

**Code**

```
type Payload = {
  start: number;
  end: number;
};

const payload: Payload = {start:1605812400,end:1605898799}
const queryString = new URLSearchParams(payload);
```

**Error**

[image]

Comment: Why can't you change start and end to string? URL can only accept strings, so you will be forced to do it anyways

Comment: @Temoncher I have to make changes in Payload type as well and the type is being used at other places so those will get disturb. Can't something be done with changing the Payload type?

Comment: You can keep payload type as is, but convert payload entries to strings on queryString creation

Comment: @r3wt URLSearchParams takes an object/record too: [see the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/URLSearchParams)

Comment: whoa, i didn't know about that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using a simple payload object including only some numbers you could generate a new object containing the values as string like this:

```js
type Payload = {
  start: number;
  end: number;
};

const payload: Payload = { start: 1605812400, end: 1605898799 };

const stringifiedPayload = Object.entries(payload).reduce<
  Record<string, string>
>((acc, [key, value]) => {
  acc[key] = String(value);
  return acc;
}, {});

const queryString = new URLSearchParams(stringifiedPayload);
```